# Misinterpretation of JSON data from Python3.3 WSGI

Tags: javascript, json, python-3.x, mod-wsgi

i am trying to send some JSON enconde data from a Web application on Python3.4/WSGI. The problem is when i try to use it, the response is a string that can't be used as an JS object. All the values of the objects come as undefined.

Here is the code of the server:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#Import Area
import sys
import json

def application(environ, start_response):

    status = '200 OK'


    response = core(environ)

    responseData = response.result()#The response of this is a dictionary {'1':"data1",'2':"data2",'3':"data3",'4':"data4"}


    status = "200 OK"
    if "type" not in  responseData:
        Ctype = "text/html"
    else:
        Ctype = responseData["type"]

    if Ctype == "application/json":
        results = json.JSONEncoder().encode(responseData["value"]) 
    else:
        results = responseData["value"]

    response_headers = [('Content-type', Ctype+"; charset=utf-8"),
    ('Content-Length', str(len(results)))]#Creating the Header of the data

    start_response(status, response_headers)#Sending the Header of the data

    return [results]#Returning the data to the web page.
```

And this is my code of Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url: "/",
    data:{"idProperty":$(this).attr("idproperty"), "code":"getPropertyData"},
    dataType:"json"
    }).done(function( response ) {
        data= response;
        console.log(response);
        console.log($.parseJSON(data));

        $(".hideall").slideDown('fast');
        $("#apto_type").val(data.TYPE);
        $("#status_prop").find("option[selected]").removeAttr('selected');
     $("#status_prop").find("option[value='"+data.STATUS+"']").attr("selected","selected");
        }).fail(function( XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              alert(  errorThrown );
        });
```

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation of your Python code? As posted it is all over the place and we cannot determine if you have a problem there or elsewhere.

Comment: Also, because you set the `dataType` to `'json'`, the `response` value passed to your `done` function is *already* decoded from JSON to a javascript object.

Comment: That part is good but the response comes in this way:{'BATHROOMS': 1.0, 'SOCIAL': True, 'NAME': 'La primera', 'BEDROOMS': 2, 'PROJECT_ID': 4, 'PRICE': 1500000.0, 'ID': 2, 'TYPE': 'Casa', 'PARKING': 2, 'STATUS': 1} As you can see the properties are string.

Comment: Yes, so? What did you expect them to be instead?

Comment: is not an object my mistake i've seen is a string that is comming. When i said the properties are string is this: 'BEDROOMS' instead it must be BEDROOMS with out the quotes.

Comment: No, all keys in an object are strings. That is *correct behaviour*.

Comment: But when i try to get the value from the key, says: undefined, also when i get the length it says that are 160.

Comment: Why don't you update your question to show what you do instead?